# Eclipse - How to know on which workspace I'm working without clicking/changing main view

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Currently working on 4 different branches in a project.

For each branch there's a different workspace in Eclipse.

Problem is when I have multiple Eclipses open on different workspace I have a hard time distinguishing between them and understanding on which workspace currently viewing. (the paths are the same so the window name is the same on all branches

I can choose to do:

`File->Switch Workspace->Other...`

and it will shows the name of current workspace but im looking for a way for it to appear in my main display windows so i don't need to do this action 100 times a day

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If the full path (as shown in the other answer) is to long, then you can use `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Workspace Name` instead to set a self defined label for each workspace, which is then shown prominently in the title bar.

Answer (score 15):

try to add the option

> -showlocation

in you eclipse.ini or in the command line when you launch Eclipse.

The workspace location will appear in the window title bar.

Comment: You can even add an argument to `-showlocation` to define your own text instead of showing the workspace path: e.g. `-showlocation "Branch 1"` . This is useful if you want to have a custom title for each eclipse installation instead of for each workspace. You can also combine this with the other answer, the workspace name is shown  on the left side of the window title and the custom text on the right.

Answer (score 5):

Go to Eclipse, Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Select the checkbox for "Show workspace path in window title"

Answer (score 2):

Add `-showlocation` to the `eclipse.ini` file located inside the eclipse folder
 or add in shortcut like below screen shot (right click on eclicpse icon-go to shortcut tab, add `-showlocation` in target field)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Edit: just right click on the project and then go to properties,it will show you the full path your project is located.
Also if you have juno ,search for "workspace" go to "workspace name (show in windows title ) and add a text like "workspace 1" and it will show you the workspace you are working at the task bar

Answer (score 0):

you can use

> Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace -> Workspace Name

or from Toolbar

> File-> Switch Workspace -> Other

**whatever the path is showing in that pop window, that is your current path.**

as @samuel told , you can add

> -showlocation

in your **eclipse.ini** also