# Variable title for eclipse workspace?

Tags: eclipse, variables, svn, branch, workspace

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15037996/1609201) shows how to set a custom title for eclipse workspace.

However, I am switching between svn branches quite often and want the title to reflect the current branch. Obviously, manually changing the workspace name every time I switch to another branch is not convenient.

Are there variables I can use in the workspace name field in order to acheive this? Or any other way?

(I'm currently working with Luna 4.4.0. Offcourse upgrading / downgrading is possible).

Comment: IMHO you have to write plugin for this. No direct way

Comment: Could you add the Subversion plugin your are using: Subclipse or Subversive? I would like to see that as a new feature in their bug database ...

Comment: I have added the "bug" to Subversive: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=449011

Comment: I use Subversive... Thanks!